# What are structs should be according to API docs to parse data from response?

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, decodable

I need structs to decode surface wind data.

https://api.windy.com/point-forecast/docs

The body of response from API docs:

```
{
    ts:int[],
    units: {
        {parameter-level}: string,
        {parameter2-level}: string,
        ...
    },
    {parameter-level}: float[],
    {parameter2-level}: float[],
    ...
```

}

Managed to decode successfully only ts:int[] to this struct:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var ts: [Int]
}
```

Also I need structs to decode data of surface wind.

Comment: There are sites like quicktype.io that can help you with your swift structures

Comment: Already used it, but still need help so quicktype can't convert it

Comment: I'd test the API to return some examples, and try to understand them. The `units` part is strange, to me, it's a `[String: String]` for sure, for `{parameter-level}: float[],`, I'd go with `let parameterLevelName: [Float],`, etc.

Comment: Then post what you have tried. And post a proper json sample

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try this approach, using dynamic keys, works in my tests:

```
struct ResponseAPI: Decodable {
    var ts: [Int]
    var units: [String:String]
    var data: [String:[Float]]

    init(ts: [Int], units: [String:String], data: [String:[Float]]) {
       self.ts = ts
       self.units = units
       self.data = data
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ts, units
    }
    
    struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?
        
        init?(stringValue: String) {  self.stringValue = stringValue  }
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil } // never used
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container1 = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.ts = try container1.decode([Int].self, forKey: .ts)
        self.units = try container1.decode([String:String].self, forKey: .units)
        self.data = [:]
        let container2 = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)
        container2.allKeys.forEach { key in
            if let theFloats = try? container2.decode([Float].self, forKey: key) {
                self.data[key.stringValue] = theFloats
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```